# scilab : can't print a simple function/variable

Tags: scilab

what I entered in editor:

```
 i1 = input("1 :");
i2 = input("2 :");
i3 = input("3 :");
i4 = input("4 :");
i5 = input("5 :");

media = (i1 + i2 + i3 + i4 + i5)/2 ;

print(media);
```

what do I get :

```
1 :2
2 :3
3 :4
4 :5
5 :6
print(media);
             !--error 42 
Incompatible input argument.
at line       9 of exec file called by :    
exec('C:\Users\*****\Documents\scilab\media2.sce', -1)
```

---

I would like to know what is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Print

[Print](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/print.html) is mostly used to print variables to a file. It could be used to print to the display, but you should give %io(2) as file argument as mentioned in [the documentation](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/print.html). So then, your code would become:

```
print(%io(2), media );
```

### Disp

The usual syntax for displaying results within Scilab is [disp](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/disp.html).

```
disp(media);
```

or

```
disp("Media is: " + string(media) );
```

### Printf

You could also use the more c-style [printf](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/printf.html) function as such

```
printf('Result is:\n media=%f',media);
```